# How can I stop Electron from "occupying" global keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am building a small music player. Like any other player, you can use your keyboards media keys (previous song, next song, play, pause) to control it, even if the app does not have focus.

---

However, when I register those shortcuts so Electron can listen for them, other apps can't use them. If my app is running, e. g. Spotify or Window's Groove won't do anything when any of those keys are pressed, because my app is already occupying those keys.

I am registering the shortcuts like this:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    globalShortcut.register('MediaPlayPause', () => {
      window.webContents.send('shortcut', 'MediaPlayPause');
    });

    globalShortcut.register('MediaNextTrack', () => {
      window.webContents.send('shortcut', 'MediaNextTrack');
    });

    globalShortcut.register('MediaPreviousTrack', () => {
      window.webContents.send('shortcut', 'MediaPreviousTrack');
    });
  }
});
```

So my question is: **is it possible to release those shortcuts whenever another app requests them?**

If yes, is it possible to re-register those shortcuts when the other app doesn't need them any longer? (let's assume the other app will unregister the shortcuts when no longer needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible from out of Electron without the use of any OS specific, native stuff. In theory, you could apply a system-wide hook on the respective functions for registering the shortcuts and work around that. Another option would be a low level keyboard hook because then you wouldn't have to register "official" listeners at all.

Other than that, i don't see how this would be possible. Quote from the globalShortcut documentation:

> This behavior is intended by operating systems, since they don't want applications to fight for global shortcuts.

Here'd be a solution for Windows based systems: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v%3Dvs.85) using SetWindowsHookEx with the WH_KEYBOARD_LL flag.

So to conclude, your best bet is to find a method (presumably a low-level keyboard hook) that will not utilize the globalShortcut API at all but instead implement your own listener in an OS specific fashion.

Comment: Hm, not a very satisfying answer, but I already thought it won't work in an easy way. Thanks anyway!